# How to set up a multiple file field on django models?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload, filefield, multiple-file-upload

I want to know which is the best way to make a FileField on a django model being able to receive multiple files and them save those files as well so they can be displayed on a template later.

I currently tried to create a model just for the file with a FK relationship with the main model but it just seems to be even worst to fix my issue.